# Use one PPA in another PPA

Tags: ppa

I would like to create a PPA for package that is not in Ubuntu yet. It has a dependency on another piece of software which isn't in the official repository either, but available from another PPA.
Is it possible to source that PPA into mine without manually copying over the packages for every new upload?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't need the PPA users to install that package and you only need it as a build dependency, you can add that other PPA as a dependency for your PPA.

To do this, go to the PPA page on Launchpad, click "Edit PPA dependencies" and there, add the PPA from which you need the dependency:

[image]

Comment: Great! So this doesn't work for runtime-dependencies by any chance?

Comment: Yes, it only works for build-dependencies. For installation, you'll either have to copy the packages to your PPA or point the users to add all the required PPAs.